# Custom Vector and Matrix classes in python for machine learning

Tags: python, performance, reinventing-the-wheel, machine-learning, neural-network

I am creating a machine learning tool set from scratch in python. I have never done something of this kind and I don't usually use python but I thought it would be good to expand my horizons. I am really looking for aspects of the code that would really hinder performance and things to consider since this will be used for a neural network implementation.

```
class vector:
    def __init__(self, size):
            self.elems = [0] * size
            self.size = size
    def __repr__(self):
            return repr(self.elems)
    def __mul__(self, other):
            if(self.size != other.size):
                    raise ArithmeticError("vectors of two different lengths")
            a = 0
            for i in range(self.size):
                    a += self.elems[i] * other.elems[i]
            return a
    def set(self, array):
            for i in range(self.size):
                    self.elems[i] = array[i]
                    self.mag =  sum([i**2 for i in self.elems])**.5
    def normalize(self):
            a =  vector(self.size)
            a.set([i/self.mag for i in self.elems])
            return(a)

class matrix:
    def __init__(self, r, c):
            self.coloums = [vector(c) for i in range(r)]
            self.r = r
            self.c = c
    def __repr__(self):
            return repr(self.coloums)
    def __mul__(self, other):
            if(type(other) != vector):
                    raise TypeError("matrices can only be multiplied by vectors")
            if(self.c != other.size):
                    raise ArithmeticError("rows and lengths do not match")
            a = vector(self.r)
            a.set([(other*self.coloums[i]) for i in range(self.r)])
            return a
    def set(self, multiarray):
            for i in range(self.c):
                    self.coloums[i].set(multiarray[i])
```

I am aware this has no way of multiply by a scalar but I have no need for that just yet and it would be pretty trivial to implement.

Comment: Is this something you are doing for learning? If not, just use numpy or one of pythons many machine learning frameworks

Comment: I think he's trying to make his own framework.

Comment: Yes the purpose is to do it on my own @Oscar I could use a library but that defeats the purpose.

Comment: (Welcome to Code Review!) (Stick to standards such as [The Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments) and [Embedded Documentation Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring).)